# python - Authorization selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm new in python. Want to login on my account
My code is:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
session = requests.Session()

url = "http://tterminal.info/"
response = session.post(url)
# <div class="auth">
authForm = driver.find_element_by_class_name("auth")
# <div class="login">
loginForm = authForm.find_element_by_class_name("login")
# Enter login
login = loginForm.find_element_by_name("login")
login.clear()
login.send_keys("mylogin")
# Enter pass
pswd = loginForm.find_element_by_name("pass")
pswd.send_keys("mypassword")
# Click login
loginForm.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()
```

But it givesme Unable to find element .auth
Where is my wrong?

Comment: Why is  there a "≠" in your python code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While working with *Selenium* you don't have to use `requests.Session()` module and your code block can be optimized as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\geckodriver.exe')
url = "http://tterminal.info"
driver.get(url)
login = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("form[name='login'] input.text[name='login']")
login.clear()
login.send_keys("mylogin")
pswd = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("form[name='login'] input.text[name='pass']")
pswd.send_keys("mypassword")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("form[name='login'] input.submit").click()
```